# How this particular merge sort program is working?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, mergesort

I am learning sorting algorithms. I have gone through a program given on the following link. For the sake of simplicity I am attaching both link and program itself.

```
public class Mergesort {
private int[] numbers;
private int[] helper;
private int number;

public void sort(int[] values) {
    this.numbers = values;
    number = values.length;
    this.helper = new int[number];
    mergesort(0, number - 1);
}

private void mergesort(int low, int high) {
    if (low < high) {
    int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
    mergesort(low, middle);
    mergesort(middle + 1, high);
    merge(low, middle, high);
    }
}

private void merge(int low, int middle, int high) {
    for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) {
        helper[i] = numbers[i];
    }
    int i = low;
    int j = middle + 1;
    int k = low;
    while (i <= middle && j <= high) {
        if (helper[i] <= helper[j]) {
            numbers[k] = helper[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            numbers[k] = helper[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (i <= middle) {
        numbers[k] = helper[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }
}
```

}

I am not getting any clue that in merge method why this last while(i<=middle) is included. Means while(j<=high) was also there, but this condition was ignored.
The link where I got this program is http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsMergesort/article.html

Sorry for my bad explanation. Hope someone can explain it to me.

Comment: Does it work? Did you try desk checking it or debugging?

Comment: Yes, it is working and producing expected output.

Answer (score 2):

The clue is actually in the referenced article:

```
            // Copy the rest of the left side of the array into the target array
            while (i <= middle) {
                    numbers[k] = helper[i];
                    k++;
                    i++;
            }
```

Consider the case when numbers in the first half are all greater than the numbers in the second half. Then in the first `while` cycle you'll only increase `j`, you will not copy any numbers from the first half. The second `while` cycle copies the remaining numbers from the first half.

A good question is why you actually don't need to copy tthe remaining numbers from the second half. I'll leave it to you. :)

Comment: Yes, the better question is why we don't need the numbers from second half to be copied. And I have got my answer. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @S.kalya - The numbers from the second half aren't needed because a copy to a temp array was done before the merge, and the merge is merging from the temp array back to the original array. If the merge sort was more efficient and alternated merge direction between original and temp buffer based on level of recursion, then there would be no copy step, and the merge would need to copy any remaining numbers from either the first or second half. In the specific case of run size == 1 and merging from original to temp, it would need to copy 1 element.